# Django Model Default Datetime with Timezone Always Midnight

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-timezone

Current field in my model is as follows...

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Test(models.Model):
    assigned_date_time = models.DateTimeField(
        null=True, verbose_name='Assigned Date', default=timezone.now)
```

When this object is created, the `assigned_date_time` is always `0` or rather "midnight" of today. I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you import `timezone`? Can you add the relevant import statement(s)?

Comment: Do you perhaps assign a value yourself when you construct a `Test`?

Comment: I feel dumb. I am an assigning a value of `datetime.date.today()` instead of just letting the default get used. Didn't even look at how I was saving it because originally I was using a naive date.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the field default to be executed, a value should not be assigned to that field.